# Getting initials from input by user Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
System.out.printf("Please enter your full name: ");
userFullName = KyBdIn.nextLine();

userFullName= userFullName.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
userFullName = userFullName.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)\\w+", ".");
userFullName = userFullName.trim().replaceAll(" +", "");

System.out.println(userFullName);
```

and I'm just wondering how it works exactly?

Is it that `\w` means white space and that the `?` questions it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Just so you know, the answer you accepted is mostly rubbish. Especially the opening line about "\w" being about whitespace... It has nothing whatsoever to do with whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes two parameters; the first is a regex (regular expression) as its search term and the second is the replacement expression (which may also contain certain regex references, but none are used here).

This line:

```
userFullName = userFullName.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

calls `trim()`, which removes leading and trailing "whitespace" characters, then calls `replaceAll()` to replace "one or more spaces" with a single space.

Because this line is repeated later, doing it twice adds no value - either could be removed with affecting the end result.

This line:

```
userFullName = userFullName.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)\\w+", ".");
```

replaces one or more word characters that are preceded by a word character with a dot. The breakdown of the regex (without java's escaping of backslashes - ie `"\\"` is a string with a single backslash) is:

- `\w` means a "word character", which is any letter, digit or underscore character
- `\w+` means "one or more word characters" (the plus sign means one or more of the preceding expression)
- `(?<=\w)` is a "look behind", which asserts that the preceding input is a "word character"

Together, the regex `(?<=\w)\w+` effectively "all but the first character of any word"

Answer (score 0):

the \w stuff is a regular expression used to filter out whitespace.

`.Trim()` removes whitespace on either end of the string

`replaceAll(" +", " ")` replaces double spaces with single spaces

`replaceAll("(?<=\\w)\\w+", ".")` replaces inner whitespace with periods. this one uses a 'look behind' operation. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

`replaceAll(" +", "")` removes any remaining spaces.